# Wcf Tcp duplex service unreachable

Tags: wcf, tcp, wcf-binding

I create a wcf service using net.tcp binding and i put it in the server and everything is going right( i can browse it,  call it and getting answer etc..

I implemented a heartbeat method in this service which is called by an application.

After a while (half a day or may be more) when i try to reach the service i get : "a connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond"

What is weird is that old client (just one)  is still connected to the service and work perfectly but i cannot call wcf service from other clients

I activated wcf tracing but there is no errors.

When i recycle the apppool the service start working normally and after a while he get the same weird behaviour..

Any idea or solution please? I start working on this issue a week ago and untill now no progress

Comment: Can you post only the relevant parts of: Service Contract (including callback), client channel code, service config, client config. Thanks